# Can't log in after installing CUDA toolkit

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login, cuda

I have latest version of Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed latest version of Cuda Toolkit 8.0. After install Cuda Toolkit, I am stucked on login screen and I can't login into Ubuntu with my password. Is there posibility to get into system? Or do you have any manual, how to corectly install Cuda toolkit? I need Cuda toolkit on Ubuntu. (Sorry for my English)

There is my procedure, how I installed Cuda (officialy from Nvidia)

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Comment: Awful isn't it. So many programs without decent error messages. If you type `CTRL+ALT+F1`, you may then be able to log in, and then uninstall; perhaps with something like `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`.

Comment: Can you login as the guest session?  If so, your login loop may be caused by the hidden "dot" files in your home directory.  Start with deleting or moving the .Xauthority file.  Search this site for login loop.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Cuda from a .run file, you are usually prompted to install nVidia drivers. If you respond by yes it will override the original drivers.  The solution that worked for me was :

1. Go to the tty by pressing ctrl-ALt-F1
2. Run `sudo uninstall-nvidia`
3. Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-X`
4. Restart your PC

   here X refers to the latest version of the driver in my case it was 67 i guess

Comment: Why nividia-current? This package installs only a a driver version for legacy hardware, the one not expected to be running CUDA. Please avoid giving this kind of wrong answers and this one is an exact copy, by the way.